# Postgres query left join take too time

Tags: sql, count, left-join, postgresql-11

i have a problem with this query. it go in loop, I mean query after 15 minutes not finish
But if remove one of the left join works
where wrong I?

```
Select distinct a.sito,
Count(distinct a.id_us) as us,
Count (distinct b.id_invmat) as materiali,
Count (distinct c.id_struttura) as Struttura,
Count(distinct d.id_tafonomia) as tafonomia
From us_table as a
Left join invetario_materiali as b on a.sito=b.sito
Left join struttura_table as c on a.sito=c.sito
Left join tafonomia_table as d on a.sito=d.sito
Group by a.sito
Order by us
```

thanks
E

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, since the GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Comment: JOINs and aggregation require some extra care. Make sure you don't count the same items several times. I'd say, when in doubt - aggregate before join.

Comment: @jarlh thanks you are right. until limit 128 works well, I mean in one second the query respond. after that utill limit 140 it needs 22-24 sec. from limit 150 i have an error : no space left on device

Comment: You could try correlated subqueries instead of the left joins.

Comment: yes I did but it is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where correlated subqueries might be the simplest approach:

```
select s.sito,
      (select count(*) from invetario_materiali m where s.sito = m.sito) as materiali,
      (select count(*) from struttura_tablest where s.sito = st.sito) as Struttura,
      (select count(*) from tafonomia_table t where s.sito = t.sito) as tafonomia
from (select sito, count(*) as us
      from us_table
      group by sito
     ) s
order by us;
```

This should be much, much faster than your version for two reasons.  First, it avoids the outer aggregation.  Second, it avoids the Cartesian products among the tables.

You can make this even faster by creating indexes on each of the secondary tables on `sito`.

Comment: thanks a lot, it works very fast! but for my resutls I changed count(*) in count(distinct..)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `id_us`, `id_invmat`, `id_struttura` and `id_tafonomia` are all `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED`

You should add indexes on join columns:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_SITO ON us_table ( sito ASC) ;
CREATE INDEX IX_SITO ON invetario_materiali ( sito ASC) ;
CREATE INDEX IX_SITO ON struttura_table ( sito ASC) ;
CREATE INDEX IX_SITO ON tafonomia_table ( sito ASC) ;
```

Than you can reduce complexity in this way:

```
with
_us_table as (
    select sito, count(distinct a.id_us) us
    from us_table a
    group by sito
),
_invetario_materiali as (
    select sito, count(distinct b.id_invmat) materiali
    from invetario_materiali b
    group by sito
),
_struttura_table as (
    select sito, count(distinct c.id_struttura) Struttura
    from struttura_table c
    group by sito
),
_tafonomia_table as (
    select sito, count(distinct d.id_tafonomia) tafonomia
    from tafonomia_table d
    group by sito
)
Select a.sito, a.us, b.materiali, c.Struttura, d.tafonomia
From _us_table as a
Left join _invetario_materiali as b on a.sito=b.sito
Left join _struttura_table as c on a.sito=c.sito
Left join _tafonomia_table as d on a.sito=d.sito
Order by a.us;
```

should be much faster

Comment: . . I agree that this should be faster.  The `count(distinct)`s should not be needed in the CTEs, though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` is difficult to improve upon using an index.  However, we can at least try adding indices which cover all the joins in your query:

```
CREATE INDEX inv_mat_idx ON invetario_materiali (sito, id_invmat);
CREATE INDEX strut_tbl_idx ON struttura_table (sito, id_struttura);
CREATE INDEX taf_tbl_idx ON tafonomia_table (sito, id_tafonomia);
```

Note that the above indices would only help the joins, and would not affect the aggregation step by `sito` and the distinct counts per group.  As @jarlh has noted in the comments, `SELECT DISTINCT` is superfluous, since you are using `GROUP BY`, so just do a plain `SELECT`.

Comment: hi, yes select distinct is superflous and the index i was already create. Now if I remove distinct it works well untill limit 128, with limit 129 it needs 22 sec, limit 140 24 sec after that go in loop. you know why?

Comment: If you've already optimized the query, and it is still too slow, then you may have to just wait for it to finish.